# How do I adjust the terminal shell window width?

Tags: gnome-terminal, window

Does anyone know how to adjust the default width for shell window in Ubuntu, so that I don't have to re-size it every time I open it up?

Comment: What do you mean by "Shell Window"?

Comment: @Marco I think what they mean by "shell window" is the window for the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to `gnome-terminal`, you can go to the menu item Edit->Profile Preferences, check "Use custom default terminal size" and put in the character dimensions you prefer.

Comment: BTW, that setting is stored in ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml by default

Comment: @l0b0: I would say that it can also be modified through `gconf-editor`, following the path `/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default`, in the values of `use_custom_default_size`, `default_size_columns` and `default_size_rows`. I would never suggest to edit the file directly.

Comment: there are 6 tabs available in my "Profile Preference" window, `General, Title and Command, Colors, Background, Scrolling, Compatibility`, and I can't find `"Use custom default terminal size"`

Comment: @user15218: in the General tab, at the bottom of it.

Comment: @user15218: The setting is not available in 10.04 alternative install, nor is there use_custom_default_size setting in gconf-editor.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to [~/.Xresources](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.Xresources) (of course with whatever dimensions you want):

```
XTerm*VT100.geometry: 96x68
```

Then add this to [~/.xinitrc](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.xinitrc):

```
xrdb -merge $HOME/.Xresources
```

That should be sufficient. Unfortunately it looks like it's necessary to log out and in again to see the changes.

Comment: why don't I have `~/.Xresources`, it says `No such file or directory`

Comment: @user15218 It's not there by default.

Answer (score 0):

With `gnome-terminal` use `Edit->Profile...`, select the default profile, then `edit`. In the next window in the general tab there is the option to select the window size. You have to open a new terminal window to see it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this with a script:

```
gconftool -s /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_custom_default_size -t bool true
gconftool -s /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/default_size_rows       -t int  60
gconftool -s /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/default_size_columns    -t int  220
gconftool -s /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/scrollback_lines        -t int  5000
gconftool -s /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_type         -t string transparent
...
```